# Missing values on second y-axis

Tags: gnuplot, multiple-axes

I want to plot 3 sets of y-values, where I want to have values for "Temperature" shown on one Y-axis, and both "Total Energy" and "Potential Energy" values shown on the other y-axis.
My plotting command is:

```
plot "traj_read.out" using 3:7 title 'Temperature' w lines, \
"traj_read.out" using 3:4 axes x1y2 title 'Total Energy' w lines, \
"traj_read.out" using 3:6 axes x1y2 title 'Potential Energy' w lines
```

The lines are displayed well, but only the values for "Temperatures" are shown on the Y-axis to the left, values on the right y-axis are missing.

Hope someone has a tip how to scale those axes!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
set ytics nomirror
set y2tics
```

The y2 axis tics are not turned on by default.